# Add link to path of an SVG in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, path, hyperlink, react-link

I have an SVG of a map that I want to add a link to in React to the path tag.

```
         <svg viewBox="0 0 777.74173 413.26299"
                version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g id="prov00p36">
                    <clipPath id="SVG_CP_1">
                        <path d="M0,0L0,413.26299L777.74173,413.26299L777.74173,0L0,0z" />
                    </clipPath  

                <path clipPath="url(#SVG_CP_1)" fill="#E8BEFF" fillRule="evenodd" 
                    stroke="none" d="M248.39427,287.05972L247.4343,286.57968
                    L247.1943,285.61962L248.39427,286.09965L248.39427,287.05972z"
                />
                </g>

         </svg>
```

Can I add a tag in the html? or do I have to create a function?

Comment: Please read about [The <a> SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.